# java problem : index.jsp file can not display to specified port?

Tags: java, jsp

I am writing a very simple demo java spring website and here is my problem.

I put the index.jsp file in this folder

```
src/main/webapp/index.jsp
```

And the file is very simple

I configured my file as the tutorial (changed all the port from 8080 to 8888), in the folder src/main/webapp/WEB-INF I made 2 files

demo-config-servlet.xml and web.xml, there were no error.

Then I ran the file index.jsp, there was no error, as you can see in this picture

[image: when I ran the file index.jsp]

But when I ran DemoSpringMVC by Run As -> Run on Server -> (I choose Tomcat v10.0)
I got this error

[image: my error]

Here is my code

```
https://github.com/nguyencuc2586/Demo
```

Do you think it is because of the port 8888 ? Or the version of Tomcat ?
Could you please give me some advices ? Thank you in advance.

Comment: The problem seems to be in the configuration of the Tomcat in your IDE. The port does not have to do anything with the JSP or your sourcecode. So which IDE do you use to perform the "Run As"?

Comment: @cyberbrain thanks for your comment, I used eclipse to ran my Demo

Answer (score 1):

Looked at your code on GitHub. There are a couple of issues in `web.xml`.

- You need to tell the `DispatcherServlet` to load the context configuration (the one you defined in the `demo-config-servlet.xml`) by specifying the `contextConfigLocation` init-param.
- Also map the dispatcher servlet correctly.

Look at the updated `web.xml` below (added comments at the sections I added/modified):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>demo-config</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    
    <!-- Mapped the servlet to '/' -->
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>demo-config</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

EDIT: Added some explanation of the changes

Spring Dispatcher servlet mapping needs to be a valid url-pattern. `/` in the pattern means that the servlet will be mapped to the 'root'

`<url-pattern>/<url-pattern>`

In your case, this should take care of the issue. However, if for some reason the context still does not load, try specifying the context configuration to the servlet by using the `<init-param>` settings given below:

```
<!-- Added the context configuration below -->
<init-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/demo-config-servlet.xml</param-value>
</init-param>
```

Read about the configuration in the docs here - https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-servlet

Comment: Thanks for your comment, your code is right but I still do not understand how it work ? ( I mean what is this code mean ? (<param-value>/WEB-INF/demo-config-servlet.xml</param-value>) ?) and some your update code ? could you please explain them for me ?